# distribute a list in python

Tags: python, distribution

Suppose I have a configuration dictionary:

```
config = {'A': 3, 'B': 4, 'C': 2}
```

How do I flat distribute (intersperse) the list like this: 
(append one by one into result list still end of all config)

```
result = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'B']
```

Another example case:

```
config = {'A': 3, 'B': 1}
result = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'A']

config = {'A': 2, 'B': 2}
result = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B']
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Show it!

Comment: You should try to solve your problem, and ask specific questions about problems encountered. This isn't a code writing service (although sometimes it seems what way.)

Comment: hi @Tichodroma muraria . I can solve this in C by a simple way. First add each config in to a matrix by row. Then print out by fetch matrix by column. What i'm question here is any other/better solution in python or especially a pythonista way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from itertools import izip_longest as izip_l, chain
config = {'A': 3, 'B': 4, 'C': 2}

# Reconstruct the list of lists
expanded = [[k] * config[k] for k in config]

# Just zip them and ignore the None
print[item for item in chain.from_iterable(izip_l(*expanded)) if item]
```

If the count is too big and if you are worried about the performance and the memory consumed, you can use `repeat` instead of reconstructing the list of lists, like this

```
from itertools import izip_longest as izip_l, chain, repeat
expanded = [repeat(k, config[k]) for k in config]
```

Rest all are the same

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`itertools` recipe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) `roundrobin` for this:

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

def roundrobin(*iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    pending = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).next for it in iterables)
    while pending:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            pending -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, pending))

result = list(roundrobin(*(k * v for k, v in sorted(config.items()))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Without any extra lib

```
main_config = {'A': 3, 'C': 4, 'B': 2}
config = main_config
list = []
for lp in range(max(config.values())):
    for key in config.keys():
        val = config.get(key)
        if val != 0:
            list.append(key)
            config.update({key:val-1})
print list
```

Output:

```
['A', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C']
```